# Removing a book from "Reading Now" vs. Deleting it

Tags: books

I have two EPUB books downloaded from a non-Apple website.

If I open Apple Books on my Mac and try to delete/remove the first of them, the app asks me whether I want to remove it from my "Reading Now" collection:

[image]

But if I try to delete/remove the second one, Books asks me whether I want to delete that book from the device. **Why?** (And by the way, no, it doesn't delete the file if I answer "Delete". Why?)

[image]

Ventura 13.2.1, Books 5.1

Comment: Were you *already* reading the book being asked to remove from the collection versus the second one which wasn't?